# Why only some classes on jar are found

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, cron4j

does anyone know how can java find only part of the jar?

I created a lib that does some reporting and I'm integrating it into many different projects. This particular error only happens on those running inside tomcat.

```
Exception in thread "cron4j::scheduler[10f8a8a406870a5b0d2142230000014bdf89373949886ac4]::launcher[10f8a8a406870a5b3adcceb60000014be0e6d840729614e1]"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/sauronsoftware/cron4j/DayOfMonthValueMatcher
    at it.sauronsoftware.cron4j.SchedulingPattern.match(Unknown Source)
    at it.sauronsoftware.cron4j.LauncherThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.sauronsoftware.cron4j.DayOfMonthValueMatcher
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
```

I checked the jar and it has the class.
Also checked if there's more than one JAR on the classpath.

Comment: Use the java -cp option to include the class in the classpath.

Comment: The class is in the classpath. You can see by the stacktrace that some classes from the same jar were found previous to the error.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have 2 versions of the JAR: for instance one in the parent/tomcat lib folder and one in a war ?

Comment: Yes, I verified that.